# Jetty 9 + Spring Boot - Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

With Jetty-starter, I was not able to launch a Spring Boot application due to this error:

```
20:23:51.548 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at xxxxxxxx.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:18) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted

> Task :bootRun FAILED
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Spring jetty starter does not work as expected and you have to add your dependencies.

Remove the starter, and add them like this post: https://medium.com/code-your-life/use-jetty9-with-spring-boot-and-gradle-85a1127c919f

```
dependencies{
  compile(“org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web”) {
    exclude module: “spring-boot-starter-tomcat”
  }
  compile ‘org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.+’
  compile ‘org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:9.+’
}
```